# Reduzir repetição de código com criação de laço (loop)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero economizar umas linhas de código criando um laço `for` ou `while` para reduzir o que está abaixo. Eu atribuiria uma variável `array` para `baixo_final[]` ficando `baixo_final[i]` por exemplo e a variável `i` iria de 0 até 14

```
document.getElementById("baixo_final[0]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[1]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[2]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[3]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[4]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[5]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[6]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[7]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[8]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[9]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[10]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[11]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[12]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[13]").className = "baixo_final_2";
document.getElementById("baixo_final[14]").className = "baixo_final_2";
```

Comment: Imagino que esses elementos são criados dinamicamente. Não seria o caso de já criar com a classe certa em vez de fazer essa volta toda?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes fazer assim com JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++){
    document.getElementById("baixo_final[" + i + "]").className = "baixo_final_2";
   // ou somente `"baixo_final" + i + ""` caso não precises de "[]"
}
```

E podes fazer aproximado com CSS usando `div[id^="baixo_final"]` que quer dizer que o ID "começa com" uma dada string. É menos específico, mas caso se aplique ao teu HTML pode ser útil. Nesse caso seria assim ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L65prrj/)):

```
div[id^="baixo_final"] {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #0A8;
}
```

Exemplo da versão com JavaScript:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
    document.getElementById("baixo_final[" + i + "]").className = "baixo_final_2";
}
```

```css
.baixo_final_2 {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #0a5;
}
```

```html
<div id="baixo_final[0]">0</div>
<div id="baixo_final[1]">1</div>
<div id="baixo_final[2]">2</div>
<div id="baixo_final[3]">3</div>
<div id="baixo_final[4]">4</div>
<div id="baixo_final[5]">5</div>
<div id="baixo_final[6]">6</div>
<div id="baixo_final[7]">7</div>
<div id="baixo_final[8]">8</div>
<div id="baixo_final[9]">9</div>
<div id="baixo_final[10]">10</div>
<div id="baixo_final[11]">11</div>
<div id="baixo_final[12]">12</div>
<div id="baixo_final[13]">13</div>
<div id="baixo_final[14]">14</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Basta criar o laço que vai variar os números. A variável de controle do laço será usada como variável da parte... (adivinha?) variável do código, assim tudo o que é repetido pode ser otimizado:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) document.getElementById("baixo_final[" + i + "]").className = "baixo_final_2";
```

Só para você ver o resultado:

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) console.log('document.getElementById("baixo_final["' + i + '"]").className = "baixo_final_2";');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Repeat.js).

Answer (score 0):

Que tal uma solução alternativa com a função [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='baixo_final']");

elementos.forEach(function(elemento) {
  elemento.classList.add("baixo_final_2");
});
```